# rails activeadmin (multi) nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to get started with active admin. I have this models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :direcctions

  validates :empresa, :presence => true
  validates :fono, :presence => true
  validates :giro, :presence => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :direccionts
end

class Direction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_one :city
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :direction
end
```

In my Activeadmin.register block for Client I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Cliente do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :empresa
      f.input :fono
      f.input :giro
    end

    f.inputs "Direcciones" do
      f.has_many :directions do |j|
        j.input :direction
        #  j.inputs "Ciudad" do
        #      j.has_one :ciudads do |r|
        #          r.input :city
        #      end
        #  end
      end
    end

    f.buttons
  end
end
```

With this i cant add multiple directions to one cliente, but i can't show the inputs to add a city to a Direction... how can i do that?? and this don't work to.. i have also this error when i try to create a client:

```
unknown attribute: client_id
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm trying the same, no good results yet. Anyway, I think there's a typo in ":direccionts". Greetings from Argentina

Comment: It seems to be too late but may be you should add your `client_id` to `permit_params`, smth. like: `permit_params :client_id`

Answer (score -1):

ActiveAdmin uses Justin French's [Formtastic gem](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), so you can use that DSL directly in your forms, for example:

```
f.inputs "Direcciones" do
  f.semantic_fields_for :directions do |j|
    j.input :direction
    j.inputs "Ciudad" do
      j.semantic_fields_for :ciudads do |r|
        r.input :city
      end
    end
  end
end
```